# Rails Controller - Cant load such file (CSV)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, controller

I have the following in my view:

```
<%= form_tag import_list_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag(:file) %>
    <%= submit_tag(:Submit) %>
<% end %>
```

I have this in my controller:

```
  def import
    require 'csv'

    csv = CSV.load params[:file].tempfile.read
    CSV.new(csv.tempfile, :col_sep => ",", :return_headers => false).each do |column|
      name_array << column[5]
      end
    redirect_to(:index)
    end
```

I'm just trying to store a temporary CSV file in memory and do some actions on it, essentially using it to pull in information to be used in consuming a web service later.

This is the error I receive:

`cannot load such file -- Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,etc....`

How can I change my controller to not throw this error?

Comment: throw some more light on how and when the error occurs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it.

```
  def import
    require 'csv'

    CSV.new(params[:file].tempfile, :col_sep => ",", :return_headers => false).each do |column|
      name_array << column[5]
      end
    redirect_to(:index)
    end
```

Another notice: Dont put your logic in your controller it belongs in the model ;)

//
That menas you should write a method in your model that deals with the data and only refere the path to the csv file as a parameter of the method. The model is there as an interface between you app and the database and for the things done in the app. The View is there to display your stuff and the controller is the thing that connects both.